# Put a ball inside a rectangle trapped inside, with some velocity and restitution

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, skshapenode

In this scene:

```
let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(300, 400))
rectangle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
rectangle.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor()
rectangle.strokeWidth = 10
self.addChild(rectangle)
```

I want to put a ball inside this rectangle, trapped inside, with some velocity and restitution, that will be bouncing and changing the vector direction when collides with one of the walls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if you can do that with SKShapeNodes and physics bodies because the physics body will apply to the whole shape node (with center).

Since you want to make the rectangle visible you can could either make a SKSpriteNode subclass with 4 SKSpriteNodes sides and than shape them as a rectangle.

Alternatively you could just draw a rectangle border in your program of choice, just make sure the centre is nothing basically, and export as PNG. Than just create a SKSpriteNode with the image.

```
  let rectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle")
  let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Rectangle")
  rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
  rectangle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
```

Now if you have drawn the rectangle correctly it will only have a physics body on the 4 sides since you did not draw a centre.

Than you simply create your ball and give it a physics body like above, with the same collision bitMask. Position it in the centre of the rectangle and give it an impulse or something. It should bounce around as you wish without leaving the rectangle.

If you are unsure about physics bodies than you need to read a bit about it, e.g
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Swift_iOS_8_Sprite_Kit_Collision_Handling_Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for marking. Out of curiosity what did you use in the end, an image or 4 SKSpriteNodes? Because I am doing something similar for my project and now drawing the rectangle doesnt seem to work anymore, it keeps pushing the ball out. Cant remember exactly how I did it. Lmao.